# Error while running Nunit 3.0.1 in Bamboo CI

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, bamboo, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I am running NUnit 3.0.1 as a build task in Bamboo CI after the MSbuild task.
I am getting the following error
Invalid argument: -xml=TestResult.xml
Running a bat file as specified in [How to run NUnit Runner in Atlassian Bamboo with NUnit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053704/how-to-run-nunit-runner-in-atlassian-bamboo-with-nunit-3)  also didnt work as it gave me the error nunit3-console.exe is not a recognized command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run NUnit Runner in Atlassian Bamboo with NUnit 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053704/how-to-run-nunit-runner-in-atlassian-bamboo-with-nunit-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo CI doesn't appear to fully support NUnit 3.X yet, see the issue [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12433).

The error you are seeing is because NUnit 3 no longer supports the `-xml` option.

Looking at the notes on the Bamboo issue, it looks like the best appoach is to run NUnit3 as a script task (using the option `--result=YOURPATH;format:nunit2` to format the results as NUnit2 would have), and then adding an NUnit Parser Task to merge the results back in.

Comment: the other question's solution didn't work but the link you have posted and the approach you explained did the trick. I was running the Nunit task with options but didn't work, but it worked when I ran it as a script task.