# Bamboo Nunit parser task incorrectly parses the results from nunit3-console.exe (25 tests were quarantined)

Tags: xml-parsing, continuous-integration, nunit, bamboo, nunit-console

In Bamboo plan I have script-task, where script body is:

```
@echo off
SET nucpath=%1
SET projectvar=%2
SET xmlvar=%3
CALL SET xmlvar=%%xmlvar:-xml=--result%%
SET outputvar=%4;format=nunit2

SHIFT
SHIFT
SHIFT
SET remvar=%2
:loop
SHIFT
if [%1]==[] GOTO afterloop
SET remvar=%remvar% %2
GOTO loop
:afterloop
REM Ensure PATH includes nunit3-console.exe or edit the line below to include full path.
%nucpath% %projectvar% %xmlvar% %outputvar% %remvar%
```

with arguments:

- ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\src\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.5.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
- "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\src\CutwiseSeleniumTests\CutwiseSeleniumTests.csproj"
- "TestResult.xml"
- "Debug"

This task work perfectly, after it I receive correct TestResult.xml file.

But in the next final task - Nunit Parser I get another wrong result, it looks like Nunit Task doesn't work properly despite parameter "format=nunit2" in script running nunit3-console.exe.

The problem is that Nunit parser defined **25 tests as skipped** [Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik3D5.png)

But in TestResult.xml I see next Test summary:

```
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01    Test Run Summary
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01      Overall result: Failed
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01      Test Count: 45, Passed: 35, Failed: 1, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 9
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01        Failed Tests - Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Invalid: 0
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01        Skipped Tests - Ignored: 9, Explicit: 0, Other: 0
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01      Start time: 2016-10-17 13:35:48Z
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01        End time: 2016-10-17 13:41:01Z
17-Oct-2016 16:41:01        Duration: 313.298 seconds
```

Here is my TestResult.xml [TestResult.xml](https://yadi.sk/d/52dfNXmox24pN)

What could be the problem, how to solve it?

Comment: Your TestResult.xml has the correct data but is not in NUnit2 format. I suggest ECHOing the command-line before it executes so you can see what is actually passed to NUnit.

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie comments, there was a nunit3 format of result instead of nunit2. I change script to

```
@echo on
SET nucpath=%1
SET projectvar=%2
SET xmlvar=%3
CALL SET xmlvar=%%xmlvar:-xml=--result%%
SET outputvar=%4;format=nunit2
SHIFT
SHIFT
SHIFT
SET remvar=%2
:loop
SHIFT
if [%2]==[] GOTO afterloop
SET remvar=%remvar% %2
GOTO loop
:afterloop
REM Ensure PATH includes nunit4-console.exe or edit the line below to include full path.
%nucpath% %projectvar% %xmlvar% %outputvar% %remvar%
```

And I pass Bamboo's arguments as

```
 "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\src\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.5.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe", "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\src\CutwiseSeleniumTests\CutwiseSeleniumTests.csproj", -xml="TestResult.xml",  --config="Debug"
```